# cern root gSystem error

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, root-framework

I try to tutorial CERN ROOT by youtube video[video title is CERN ROOT tutorial for beginners - 3. Write a Tree with struct and class (example 4-5)], but it doesn`t worked.

> error : unknown type name 'particle_CLASS'

this is my code

```
void example5() {
   TTree t("t","a simple Tree with struct")
   gSystem->Load ("particle_CLASS_h.so");
   particle_CLASS* sParticle = new particle_CLASS();

   t.Branch ("particle_info", &sParticle);
   sParticle->Set_energy(11);
   sParticle->Set_position(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
   t.Fill();

   sParticle->Set_energy(99);
   sParticle->Set_position(191., 291., 391.);
   t.Fill();

   TFile f("example5.root","recreate");
   t.Write();
   f.Close();
   }
```

and partivle_CLASS.h code

```
class particle_CLASS: public TObject {
private:
    Float_t position[3]; 
    Float_t energy; 
public:
    particle_CLASS() { } // empty constructor
    //----Setter----
void Set_position(Float_t x, Float_t y, Float_t z) 
{
    position[0] = x; position[1] = y; position[2] = z;        
}


void Set_energy(Float_t e) { energy = e;}

//----Getter----
Float_t* Get_position() { return position; }
Float_t  Get_energy()   { return energy; }

ClassDef(particle_CLASS,1)  
/*
|   ClassDef is a C preprocessor macro 
|   that must be used if your class derives from TObject.
*/
};
```

Comment: can you give us a bit more information what you're doing to run these two files? Are you loading them in the root interpreter / cling: `root ; .L particle_CLASS.h ; .L example5.C` ? are you loading one or both with compilation `.L example5.C+`? In another direction: can you run the tutorial `$ROOTSYS/tutorials/tree/tree4.C` ?

Comment: ok. here is full code. and i`m not try running tree4.C turtorial, just study youtube tutorial video.

Comment: The code is useful, but in order to let us help you you also need to let us know exactly how you are executing it. It looks like the problem is that the "particle_CLASS_h.so" file is missing. To generate it, you need to do something lime ".L particle_CLASS.h" from the ROOT interpreter, as @pseyfert said.

Comment: oh... i'm so sorry. my mistake. "particle_CLASS_h.so" can create by commend `.x particle_CLASS.h++` in root. So, i'm creating "particle_CLASS_h.so" by "particle_CLASS.h" before running main code. and then run it. but it didn`t worked.